# GTK3 e MSYS2 compiling data

Tags: c, gcc, gtk3, msys2

i've installed in my windows 10 system GTK3.0 for mingw64 by MSYS2 but i've got a problem with pkg-config. When i write in the shell:

```
$ pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0
```

I got the following error:

```
Package gtk+-3.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+-3.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'gtk+-3.0', required by 'virtual:world', not found
```

What's the deal?

Comment: How did you install gtk? What does `pkg-config --list-all | grep -i gtk` print? What MSYS2 environment do you use? (indicated by the magenta text in the terminal prompt, normally `MSYS` or `MINGW64`)

Comment: In what shell did you install gtk3: msys2, mingw32, mingw64, clang ...?